# How to remove spaces between strings in angularjs for jhipster application

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

There is an entity called vehicle. In that for some fields (Source & Destination), i am using Google place Auto complete. If i try to submit the form, getting the following error

Error : Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify.

If i remove the whitespaces and submit the form, its working normal.

Eg: Bangalore, Karnataka ---->its giving error
    Bangalore,Karnataka------> Working Fine.

Please suggest me , to remove whitespaces in this textfield before submitting the form in angularjs code.

Filter.js:

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

angular
    .module('iloadsappApp')

    .filter('whitespace', function () {  
  return function (input) {  
       if (input) {  
            return input.replace(/[\s]/g, '');  
       }  
  }
    })
})();
```

Tried using replace function in angularjs to remove the whitespaces, but getting replace is not a function error !

Comment: Provide some code, it is hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Mistalis .. I was trying to use one filter to remove the whitespaces. But getting replace is not a function error. Please look at the actual question. Included the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `"use strict";` before using `replace`. Also you need to check if the string (**input**) is not null.

Also you can try:

```
 return String(input).replace(/[\s]/g, '');
```

Comment: As u said, if the input is not null, its working fine. But in my case, i want to achieve this before the form submitting the form. (i.e) if the user types Bangalore, karnataka, i want to submit without spaces. Any solutions for that ?

Comment: You can use `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"` to force the user to not include any whitespaces in the input string.

Comment: Here i am using google space autocomplete api  for that field :( So if user types newyork, google autocomplete api gives, Newyork, USA. So i cannot use ng-pattern here :(